# how to extract contextual data from tables to train custom named entity recognizer?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, named-entity-recognition, data-extraction

I have document containing tables and I want to extract contextual information(ex. sentences or any other form) so I can tag them and build named entity recognizer.

Is anyone knows how can we build contextual training data to train named entity recognizer or how can we annotate table data to train named entity recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try building a customer NER with Spacy. The script can be adapted to your needs.

Spacy NER format: [https://dataturks.com/help/dataturks-ner-json-to-spacy-train.php]

If you have a very fixed PDF layouts, you can convert them to Text and annotate using this tool. This provides a Prodigy like annotation experience for free.

Doccano Annotation tool: [https://github.com/chakki-works/doccano]

Answer (score 0):

The [spacy-annotator](https://github.com/ieriii/spacy-annotator) is a good solution for your problem.

It allows you to annotate custom entities in your text using ipywidgets.
Also, the annotator generates output in a format that the nlp library spaCy likes.

Annotation example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from spacy_annotator.pandas_annotations import annotate as pd_annotate

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'full_text' : ['New York is lovely but Milan is amazing!']})

# Annotations
pd_dd = pd_annotate(df,
            col_text = 'full_text',     # Column in pandas dataframe containing text to be labelled
            labels = ['GPE', 'PERSON'], # List of labels
            sample_size=1,              # Size of the sample to be labelled
            delimiter='~',              # Delimiter to separate entities in GUI
            model = None,               # spaCy model for noisy pre-labelling
            regex_flags=re.IGNORECASE   # One (or more) regex flags to be applied when searching for entities in text
            )

# Example output
pd_dd['annotations'][0]
```